# Json.writes[List[Foo]] as "map"

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a `case class Foo(bars: List[Bar])` who is rendered as json via Json inception as an object with an array :

```
{"bars": [
   { 
     "key: "4587-der",
     "value": "something" 
   }
 ]
}
```

But I want to render the `bars: List[Bar]` as a "map" where `Bar.key` is used as key :

```
{"bars":{
    "4587-der": {
      "value": "something"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I obtains that without modifying my case class `Foo` ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should mention in the tags that your code is in scala (and maybe also in your post). You should also provide the foo class' code

Comment: The `Foo` is a case class and all his code is un his declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `Writes` for `Bar` by extending `Writes[Bar]` and implementing a `writes` method for it:

```
case class Bar(key: String, value: String)

implicit object BarWrites extends Writes[Bar] {
    def writes(bar: Bar): JsValue = Json.obj(
        bar.key -> Json.obj("value" -> bar.value)
    )
}

scala> Json.stringify(Json.toJson(Bar("4587-der", "something")))
res0: String = {"4587-der":{"value":"something"}}
```

For those that may be interested, here is a (somewhat) crude implementation of `Reads[Bar]`:

```
implicit object BarReads extends Reads[Bar] {
    def reads(js: JsValue): JsResult[Bar] = js match {
        case JsObject(Seq((key, JsObject(Seq(("value", JsString(value))))))) => JsSuccess(Bar(key, value))
        case _ => JsError(Seq())
    } 
}

scala> Json.parse(""" [{"4587-der":{"value": "something"}}] """).validate[List[Bar]]
res11: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[List[Bar]] = JsSuccess(List(Bar(4587-der,something)),)
```

Edit, since the OP wants the `Bar`s merged into an object rather than an array:

You'll also have to define a special `Writes[List[Bar]]` as well:

```
implicit object BarListWrites extends Writes[List[Bar]] {
    def writes(bars: List[Bar]): JsValue = 
        bars.map(Json.toJson(_).as[JsObject]).foldLeft(JsObject(Nil))(_ ++ _)
}

scala> val list = List(Bar("4587-der", "something"), Bar("1234-abc", "another"))
list: List[Bar] = List(Bar(4587-der,something), Bar(1234-abc,another))

scala> Json.stringify(Json.toJson(list))
res1: String = {"4587-der":{"value":"something"},"1234-abc":{"value":"another"}}
```

Comment: But that is going to produce an array.. however I don't want an array.
Your `BarWrites` with a `List[Bar]` will produce `[{"4587-der":{"value":"something"}}, {"1234-abc":{"value":"another"}}]` while I need `{"4587-der":{"value":"something"}}, {"1234-abc":{"value":"another"}}` (note the absence of `[ ]`)

Comment: @Anonymous That's not valid JSON, so it'll never work.

Comment: You'r right. Sorry the expected Json is `{
    "4587-der": {
        "value": "something"
    },
    "1234-abc": {
        "value": "another"
    }
}`

Comment: @Anonymous That wasn't obvious from the original question. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had something similar but much less elegant `val json = Json.obj();
bars.foreach{b => bars + (b.key, Json.obj("value" -> b.value))}`